# Cache not big enough for installation

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing ROS-Indigo on Windows Virtual Box Ubuntu 14.04.
I set the size of the virtual disk to be fixed at 30G.
What do I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223162/cache-not-big-enough-for-installation/) by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're trying to install more stuff. I'd recommend making the disk bigger. https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualbox+increase+disk+size

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0